# Need to create an online ecommerce marketplace like foodzie or etzy. What are my open source options?

Tags: php, drupal, open-source, e-commerce, magento-1.4

In addition, i will need it to be scalable and highly customizable. For example, consumers will be able to group together in a yahoo groups/social networking fashion and then discuss and buy together as a group; merchants will have minimum volumes and time tools similar to those available on present group purchasing sites. (http://groupbuyingsite.com/). Are there plugins for each of these things? Can they be integrated together? Is plugins to open source the only route to go? As there is alot of customization going on here should i write from start?

Answer (score 1):

[Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) is a good option for Drupal! You may also want to look at [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og)

Answer (score 1):

No idea on group buying plugins and workflow.
But for php,mysql based multi-vendor shopping cart (Marketplace)
I have done a research !!!

[CS cart](http://www.cs-cart.com/) multivendor edition is your only option as of now.

First of all there are very few options available :

1. [CS cart multi vendor](http://www.cs-cart.com/multivendor.html)
2. [X-cart pro](http://www.x-cart.com/mall_solution.html)
3. osCommerce based implementations
4. [iScprits](http://www.iscripts.com/multicart/)
5. [PHP mall](http://www.netartmedia.net/mall/features.html)
6. [PHP multi shop](http://php-multishop.com/)  - php nuke based

X-cart pro 4.0 was the best but they have discontinued their development for this version and moving to a new architecture with 5.0, so its a no no.

read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625078/any-good-tutorial-available-on-how-to-write-extensions-modules-for-x-cart

Rest of the options which I mentioned above are old implementation and doesn't have hooks/api without which customization is messy.

CS cart mve has is the youngest of them (march 2011) and have hooks implementation for custom addon development.

Magento, prestashop or shopify, none of them has marketplace capability.   There is a small module available for dropshipping (magento) but it can't be used for marketplace.  And I feel marketplace development goes against magento's basics and I don't at all hope to see this after ebay acquiring them and launcing x.commerce platform.

Comment: Hi Shikhar. Thanks for your detailed answer. You say ubercart is a good solution but then you say CS cart is my only option, Why not ubercart?

Comment: What about unirgy for magento or prospress for wondpress. Do you have any thoughts on them?

Comment: I never evaluated ubercart, I was not looking for a cms cum cart. Unirgy is small module, not a multi vendor in true sense. You probably don't even have vendor login there.

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop, Magento and OSCommerce are widely used.  Shopify is quite good too and comes with plugins contributed by its active community.  Shopify was originally built on Ruby but they recently launched a PHP version as well.